# Operate on and update a value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an initial value `x` and a list of operators, call them `op1`, `op2`, `op3`, etc.

The value I would like to compute is `op1(op2(op3(x)))`. The number of operators is variable. What is the most Ruby way to do this?

Here is an example in code:

```
class Op1
  def operate arg
    arg + 1
  end
end

class Op2
  def operate arg
    arg + 2
  end
end

x = 1
Op1.new.operate(Op2.new.operate(x))
=> 4
```

Comment: What are the operators? Are they method objects? or symbols representing method names? Something else?

Comment: Assume each operator is an object that responds to a `operate(arg)` message.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If you had `m = method(:puts)`, then `m.operate(arg)` would not work. What is `operate`?

Comment: Added an example showing how this should work.

Comment: Where are `op1`, `op2`, etc.? You still haven't shown them. Is `Op1.new.operate(Op2.new.operate(x))` supposed to be somehow related to `op1(op2(op3(x)))`? Note that `Op1.new.operate`, `Op2.new.operate` etc. do not make sense; they are not an object.

Comment: Just put all your operators in an array, then iterate and apply (hint: Enumerable#reduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce. e.g.

```
 def a1(v)
   "#{v} 1"
 end

 def a2(v)
   "#{v} 2"
 end

 def a3(v)
   "#{v} 3"
 end

 puts [:a1, :a2, :a3].reverse.reduce("hi"){|memo, obj|
   self.send(obj, memo)
 }
 # gives "hi 3 2 1"
```

In your case, call:

```
[Op1, Op2].reverse.reduce(x){|memo,obj| obj.new.operate(memo)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way.

**Code**

```
methods = [[Op1, :operate1], [Op1, :operate1], ...]

def compound(methods, x)
  methods.size.times { c,m = methods.pop; x = c.send(m,x) }
  x
end
```

I have assumed that `:operate1` and `:operate2` are class methods.  The question refers to instance methods.  Those could be invoked by creating instances of the classes, but since those instances would have no further use I do not see much point in that.

Operate on a copy of `methods` if `methods` is not to be modified.

**Example**

```
class Op1
  def self.operate arg
    arg + 1
  end
end

class Op2
  def self.operate arg
    arg + 2
  end
end

methods = [[Op1, :operate], [Op2, :operate]] 
compound(methods, 1)
  #=> 4
```